# Indexer Syntax clojure clr

Tags: clojureclr

how can i access indexers of a class using clojure clr ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/indexers

I tried things like `(key object)` but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

End up writing some c# to be called from clojure to expose the indexers.